# Looking for movie with telekinetic lockpicking

Tags: story-identification, movie, powers

I remember watching a movie. Where protagonist gets hit by a lightning and gains minor telekinesis. Then he joins group of other super powered individuals. Then he opens a lock with telekinesis.

One of the other super powered dudes super power was stinking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like "[Three Inches](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2151885/)", a TV movie released in 2011 as a pilot for a proposed TV series. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Inches):

> The show follows a group of people with superhuman abilities, focusing
> on Walter Spackman, played by Noah Reid, an underachiever who develops
> a telekinetic ability after being struck by lightning.

The "three inches" of the title refers to the distance he can move objects telekineticlly.

He is recruited to join a team of superheroes, who also have quite underwhelming superpowers. One of them is Carlos, known as "The Human Smell", who can emit a pungent gas through his pores.